# regex match is true but returning weird symbols

Tags: c++, regex, linux, ubuntu, boost

I'm using boost 1.62 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
I was using the same code and files on Scientific Linux 7.2 with boost 1.53 and it was working.

This is part of the code:

```
boost::cmatch what ;
const boost::regex exp ("(\\w+).txt",boost::regex::perl);
  if(boost::regex_match((*roc).second->getCalibrationFilePath().c_str(), what, exp, boost::match_extra))
        { 
           std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< " (*roc).second->getCalibrationFilePath().c_str() " << (*roc).second->getCalibrationFilePath().c_str() << std::endl;
            std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<     "what[1] " <<       what[1] << std::endl;
            std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<     "exp " <<       exp << std::endl;
            calibrationFileRadix = what[1];
        }
        else
        {
            STDLINE("ERROR: Can't find the extension .txt in " + (*roc).second->getCalibrationFilePath(), ACRed);
            continue;
        }
```

The file name that should match is something like /path/file_name.txt and I'd like to have file_name.txt as what[1].

The outputs that I get are:

bool calibrationLoader::loadAllCalibrationFiles() (*roc).second->getCalibrationFilePath().c_str() CalGain_downstream_2016_04_05_3_0_4.txt

bool calibrationLoader::loadAllCalibrationFiles()what[1] pO���

bool calibrationLoader::loadAllCalibrationFiles()exp (\w+).txt

or

bool calibrationLoader::loadAllCalibrationFiles() (*roc).second->getCalibrationFilePath().c_str() CalGain_downstream_2016_04_05_3_0_4.txt

bool calibrationLoader::loadAllCalibrationFiles()what[1]

bool calibrationLoader::loadAllCalibrationFiles()exp (\w+).txt

Thanks!

ADD

I tested this regexp at http://www.regextester.com/ : it behaved as expected using (\w+).txt instead of (\w+).txt

Comment: Not familiar with `boost::regex`, but is there a reason the answer would be `what[1]` instead of `what[0]`?

Comment: because what[0] contains the whole string and  what[1] contains the response code and what[1] was giving the right results when I was using the code on Scientific Linux. Also, what[0] is empty now.